# Webscraping - Python - attribute href

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I got the fallowing:

```
<h4><a class="" href="https://www.eloscimento.com.br/diversos/" title="Diversos">Diversos</a></h4>,
<h4><a class="" href="https://www.eloscimento.com.br/pintura/" title="Pintura">Pintura</a></h4>,
```

I am trying to get only the attribute href in this html website. My script:

```
request = requests.get('https://www.eloscimento.com.br')

site_html = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'html.parser')
site_html

h4 = site_html.find_all('h4')
h4.get('href')
```

I'm learning beautifulsoup and selenium and i appreciate if you guys help me with this error. Thanks!!!

Comment: as you are using `find_all()` you are creating a list of elements. Therefore to get the items you should instead do `for item in h4: print(item.get('href'))` so that you can access each individual element and print out the href for that element

Comment: Hi, Andrew. I've tried what you said and i got this return:

for item in h4:
    print(item.get('href'))

output:
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None

Comment: Yeah it is outputting None because the item that you want to get is to first get the `a` tag's `href` which is not what you are doing you are just getting the h4 item's href which there is none.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Andrew, I want to get the url. I want all of then in a list. 

 - In this case, i want url: 
** https://www.eloscimento.com.br/diversos/
** https://www.eloscimento.com.br/pintura/

but when I try to get the url, my output is printing 
<h4><a class="" href="https://www.eloscimento.com.br/diversos/" title="Diversos">Diversos</a></h4>

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here:

- You're trying to run `.get` on *list* of tags (which is what `find_all` returns), when it's meant to be used directly on individual tags
- The `h4` tag doesn't *have* a `href` attribute - that belongs to the `a` tag *inside* the header tag, so even if you defined it as `h4 = site_html.find('h4')` (to get just the *first* `h4` tag), `h4.get('href')` would still return `None`

You would need

```py
h4 = site_html.find('h4')
h4.a.get('href')
```

to get the first `href` you want, and even that would raise an error if the first `h4` in the page did not contain an `a` tag ....

---

---

You can use

```py
[h.a.get('href') for h in site_html.find_all('h4') if h.find('a') and h.a.get('href')]
```

or, with [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php),

```py
[a.get('href') for a in site_html.select('h4 a[href]')]
```

---

Either of the above should return

```
['https://www.eloscimento.com.br/diversos/',
 'https://www.eloscimento.com.br/pintura/',
 'https://www.eloscimento.com.br/acabamento/',
 'https://www.eloscimento.com.br/basico/',
 'https://www.eloscimento.com.br/eletrica/',
 'https://www.eloscimento.com.br/ferramentas/',
 'https://www.eloscimento.com.br/hidraulica/',
 'https://www.eloscimento.com.br/metais/',
 '#mobileMenui40',
 '#mobileMenui55',
 '#mobileMenui326',
 '#mobileMenui73',
 '#mobileMenui91',
 '#mobileMenui214',
 '#mobileMenui240',
 '#mobileMenui375',
 'https://www.eloscimento.com.br/cabecotes/',
 'https://www.eloscimento.com.br/climatizadores/']
```

Comment: I love you, man. Its exctly what i need. I'm mean, seriously, thank you!!!!!